# Is there a way to get info about a video using AppleScript?

Tags: video, applescript

So I have a video that I want to know the length, the resolution and the framerate of. Using methods like:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to return info for "/path/to/my/video"
```

doesn't return either of those three. I'm aware that all of these can be found using [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org), but if possible, I want to avoid that.

Comment: If the information is not in the Spotlight metadata, you will need to use a utility such as FFmpeg or ExifTool unless you want to try to read Exif metadata yourself (if it is there).

Comment: @red_menace Do you mean the `Get Info` button in Finder when you say Spotlight metadata?

Comment: mkv is a second-class citizen on the mac. If you run mdls on an mp4 file, you can get info such as duration, pixel width/height, bit rates, etc…, whereas with an mkv, you will typically only get standard Finder info. I should add that if you look at 'more info' in the 'get info' window, you will see stuff for the mp4 but nothing for the mkv.

Comment: An alternative to exiftool is mediainfo. You should be able to find it in the app store. It has a gui with multiple levels of output detail and also comes with a command line. If you use complex mkv (e.g. multiple audio or sub tracks, chapters) you should find that it provides a broader range of data.

Comment: @Mockman Would be a good option but sadly, for me at least, it costs one dollar. I want other people to use the script I made, that's why I even wrote this question. I could have found how to do it with FFMPEG on my own, but not everybody has FFMPEG.

Comment: Makes sense. I wanted to offer a good alternative and FWIW, having used the app since before the app store, I think it's well worth its cost (including the lifetime price).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using ExifTool

I like using [**ExifTool**](https://exiftool.org) over **Spotlight** (`mdls`) because I keep a lot of items on *volumes* that are not indexed, and **ExifTool** reads the *meta-data* directly from the *file*.

In **Terminal**, e.g.:

```bash
% exiftool -Duration -ImageSize -VideoFrameRate '/path/to/video.mkv'  
Duration                        : 0:48:49
Image Size                      : 712x480
Video Frame Rate                : 29.97
%
```

Using **AppleScript**, here is an *example* using the `-T` *option*.

```applescript
set foo to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool -T -Duration -ImageSize -VideoFrameRate '/path/to/video.mkv'"

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tab
set duration to first text item of foo
set resolution to second text item of foo
set frameRate to third text item of foo
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""

log duration
log resolution
log frameRate
```

Output in the **Messages** *tab* of the **Log** *pane* of **Script Editor**:

```
(*0:48:49*)
(*712x480*)
(*29.97*)
```

<sup>The actual *value* of the *variable* does not contain `(*` and `*)`, as that is just how it get logged.</sup>

**Notes:**

There are may *options* that can be invoked, so you'll need to read its *manual page*.

The web site itself has a wealth of information too.

---

### Using `mdls`

For **macOS** native `mdls` in **Terminal**:

```bash
% mdls -name kMDItemDurationSeconds -name kMDItemPixelHeight -name kMDItemPixelWidth -name kMDItemVideoBitRate '/path/to/video.mp4'
kMDItemDurationSeconds = 2650.582
kMDItemPixelHeight     = 406
kMDItemPixelWidth      = 720
kMDItemVideoBitRate    = 891
%
```

You could use the `do shell script` *command* in **AppleScript** to glean the info and then parse is to fit your needs.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set foo to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdls -name kMDItemDurationSeconds -name kMDItemPixelHeight -name kMDItemPixelWidth -name kMDItemVideoBitRate /path/to/video.mp4")

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "= "
set duration to second text item of first item of foo
set resHeight to second text item of second item of foo
set resWidth to second text item of third item of foo
set bitRate to second text item of fourth item of foo
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""

set resolution to resWidth & "x" & resHeight

log duration
log resolution
log bitRate
```

Output in the **Messages** *tab* of the **Log** *pane* of **Script Editor**:

```
(*2650.582*)
(*720x406*)
(*891*)
```

<sup>The actual *value* of the *variable* does not contain `(*` and `*)`, as that is just how it get logged.</sup>

**Notes:**

You may find that even on indexed *volumes* some information will not be available to `mdls` where it may/will be with **ExifTool**.

I did not see anything in the *files* I tested with `mdls` that said *frame rate*, so I added `kMDItemVideoBitRate` to the *example* **shell script** *command*.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using third party shell modules?

Comment: @gurkensaas, I added For **macOS** native `mdls` in **Terminal**: to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the native support, I've got two questions though: 
1. If I use the `mdls` command you provided in the terminal, it doesn't give me the answer, it just gives me an `>`. 
2. "...in the files I tested with `mdld` that said frame rate..." Do you mean `mdls`?

Comment: @gurkensaas, There was an `"` at the end of the _command_ for use in **Terminal**, sorry, and yes `mdls`, as `mdld` was an auto-correct I didn't notice.

Comment: @gurkensaas, RE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68719100/is-there-a-way-to-skip-to-the-next-instruction-when-using-node-even-though-it-ha --  Instead of deleting it, why not post an answer?

Comment: It was so basic that anyone actually trying to do this is going to understand it: The `localhost` always stays open.